# Prime divisor of the form $4k+3$

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that $4m-1$ for positive integer $m$ has at least one prime divisor of the form $4k+3$.

If $4m-1$ is prime then we are done since $4m-1$ is of the form $4k+3$. What do we do in the case it isn't prime?

Comment: The product of the primes Mod 4 must be minus 1.

Comment: 4m, and 4m +2 can not be prime.  The only possible primes must be 4k + 1 and 4k +3.  Notice (4k +1)^2 = 4 (4k^2+ 2k)+1 is ALSO in the form of 4k+1.  So inductive any number whose prime factors are all in form 4k+1 will be in 4k+1.  4m-1 is NOT in form 4k+1 so it must have at least one prime factor not in form 4k+1.  The only other form for a prime is 4k+3.

Answer (score 4):

Since $4m-1$ is odd, all its prime factors must be odd as well.  If all its prime factors were congruent to $1 \mod 4$, then their product would also be congruent to $1 \mod 4$, contradicting the fact that our number is of the form $4m-1$ (because $4m-1 \equiv 3 \mod 4$)

---

Furthermore, the case where the divisor is not necessarily prime, consider the **number** of prime divisors congruent to $3 \mod 4$.  If there were an even number of them, then our number $4m-1$ should be a product of an even number of primes $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$ and possibly some primes $q \equiv 1 \mod 4$.  Since there is an even number of such $p$, we know this product must be $1 \mod 4$, which is not true (again because $4m-1 \equiv 3 \mod 4$).

Therefore, there must be an odd number of $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$, so any divisor $d\mid 4m-1$ having an odd number of these $p$ with be congruent to $3 \mod 4$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Look at the possible results of taking products of combinations of $0, 1, 2$ modulo $4$.